# What is the duration of time needed if heating activated carbon at 100 degrees celsius to recharge?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have 5 pounds of loose activated bamboo charcoal that I am using as an odor absorber.  When I need to recharge it, I would like to heat it to 100 degrees celsius.  How long does it need to remain at this temperature to recharge, that is, de-adsorb anything on its surface?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that the temperature to remove the odor agent depend on the odor components.
In the industry you will have a time/temperature protocol with three steps.
First near 100°C (a little more), to remove humidity from the activated carbon.
Then a temperature dependant of the adsorbed component. (around 400° commonly).
Finally above 700°C to reactivate the carbon (making sure is very porouse again).
If you have a lot of humidity you can restore a lot of the adsorbent power with 100°C. This is not uncommon.
There is not specific amount of time (depends on several variables), you can know by the weight profile.
If your adsorbed components have more afinity than 100°C. You will have to increase the temperature.
Best Regards.